# Using the Shopify API how can I get tax details on individual line items?

Tags: api, shopify

In the UK some items have VAT charged on them while others don't. To import orders into our back office system we need to know whether tax was charged on particular items in the order. Ideally we'd also like to know how much tax was charged on each line item.

This information isn't shown in any of the example responses given in the online docs. Is it possible to get it via the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is currently not available for individual line items, all that is available is the overall taxes charged. You could use this and `taxable` field on `Product` to attempt to divide the taxes charged.

Comment: Fair enough. This doesn't seem like a particularly unusual requirement for a UK shop, any prospect of this being built into Shopify?

Comment: It's likely to be added, no timelines as to when though.